# Variable C not changing when programmed to change?

Tags: c#

Extremely perplexed at why "c" won't change when I program it to change. Not much else to say, probably a stupid mistake but can't figure it out...

```
//declared OUTSIDE of the method.        
private string c = "1";

private void expanded(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    if (debug2.Text == "Temp")
    {
        if (c == "1")
        {
            c = "2";
            ((Storyboard)this.Resources["_in"]).Begin();
        }
        if (c == "2")
        {
            c = "1";
            ((Storyboard)this.Resources["_in1"]).Begin();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are values of `debug2.Text` and `c` when the method is called?

Comment: c = 1 and debug2.text = temp.

Comment: Is debug2.Text equal to "temp" or "Temp"?

Comment: @Dave that was a typing mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You’re missing an `else`:

```
    if (c == "1")
    {
        c = "2";
        ((Storyboard)this.Resources["_in"]).Begin();
    }
    else if (c == "2") // !!!
    {
        c = "1";
        ((Storyboard)this.Resources["_in1"]).Begin();
    }
```

Otherwise you’re setting `c` to `"2"` and then immediately back to `"1"`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do?

```
private: // <-- remember the colons (:)
     string c = "1";

     void expanded()
     {
        if(c = "1")
        {
           c = "2";
           ((Storyboard)this.Resources["_in"]).Begin(); //dono what this is
        }

        if(c == "2")
        {
           c = "1";
           ((Storyboard)this.Resources["_in1"])Begin(); //dono what this is
        }
     }
```

BUT!!! and this is a big but(t) :)
Don't think that this can be done in C language since it dose not have any classes other that struct{}, but that is not really a class you can't have methods in them.

YOU CAN DO IT IN C++ you just need to remember to #include

Comment: OP is talking about C#, not C++